# Disallowing non-attribute parameters in a Moose Class

Tags: perl, parameters, constructor, moose

Is there a way to die if there are extra parameters in a constructor call in Moose that are not attributes?  For example, this:

```
package Shoe;
use Moose;
has 'size'  => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Num');
has 'color' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', default => 'brown');
1;
```

would die on

```
my $sneaker = Shoe->new(size => 11, colour => 'white');
```

because `colour` is not an attribute of `Shoe`.

I could swear I've seen a module or something to do this but I can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me works [MooseX::StrictConstructor](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::StrictConstructor):

```
package Shoe;
use Moose;
use MooseX::StrictConstructor; # <-- that's all what need
has 'size'  => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Num');
has 'color' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str');
1;

package main;
my $sneaker = Shoe->new(size => 11, colour => 'white'); #blows up
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew that was out there and I couldn't remember the name.  The perils of getting old...

Comment: @BillRuppert - So in 10 years (exactly) I will do the same ;) :)